# Как мне реализовать пробный период в телеграмм боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Телеграмм бот с БД, как мне лучше сделать "пробный период", что бы после 3-х использований функций выдавало запрос о покупке ?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def Welcome(message):
    if (not BotDB.user_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        BotDB.add_user(message.from_user.id)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Тест')

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['next'])
def Command(message):
    if (not BotDB.user_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        BotDB.add_user(message.from_user.id)
    if (BotDB.user_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        global tag
        if tag < 3:
            answer_bot = random.shuffle(cells)
            answer_bot = random.choice(cells)

            markup_menu_button = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
            item_ppp = types.KeyboardButton('###')
            item_dostyp = types.KeyboardButton('###')
            item_info = types.KeyboardButton('##')
            item_referal = types.KeyboardButton('###')
            markup_menu_button.row(item_ppp, item_dostyp)
            markup_menu_button.row(item_referal)
            markup_menu_button.row(item_info)

            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Собеседник найден \n/next – искать нового собеседника\n/stop – закончить диалог', reply_markup = markup_menu_button)
            time.sleep(3)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, ''+str(answer_bot)+'', reply_markup = markup_menu_button)
            time.sleep(2)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Собеседник закончил с вами связь \nНапишите /search чтобы найти следующего')

            tag = tag + 1
            print(tag)
        elif i >= 3:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'конец')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавил, мне нужно что бы функция 'next' выполнилась не более 3-х раз, я попытался добавить счётчик итераций но он работает для всех

Comment: @TimLofer тут потребуется хотя бы небольшая, но база данных где будут храниться id пользователя и сколько раз он уже использовал пробник. И дальше простая проверка кол-ва